# tmux not splitting panes with desired percentage size

Tags: tmux, size, panel

I am trying to create a script that launches tmux with a specific pane layout and size. I am following the tutorial in the following link:
https://leanpub.com/the-tao-of-tmux/read#pane-resizing

However when I try to use `tmux split-window -p 75` it's more like a 40%/60% split. I've also tried `tmux split-window -p 90` to see if I could get a bigger, and more evident, difference in size between the two panes but it doesn't change much.

These is the code that I am using:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new -s abc -d
tmux split-window -p 90
tmux attach -t abc
```

I know how to create the layout that I want but my problem is getting the pane sizes that I need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `new-session`
>   […] With `-d`, the initial size comes from the global `default-size` option; `-x` and `-y` can be used to specify a different size.

<sup>([source](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#new-session))</sup>

The default `default-size` is `80x24`. Before customizable `default-size` was introduced, `new-session` behaved as if it was `80x24`.

What happens is `split-window` works fine. Then you `attach` and the layout is recalculated to the new width and height. My observation is `tmux` tends to keep the size of some pane(s) while resizing, it doesn't keep the relative proportions. I don't think you can change this behavior easily.

Tell `new-session` to use the [size of your terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263900/10765659):

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -s abc -d -x "$(tput cols)" -y "$(tput lines)"
tmux split-window -p 90
tmux attach -t abc
```

Comment: Is possible to use "-" for sizes: `tmux new-session -s abc -d -x - -y -`