# Modify tmux run-shell PATH

Tags: zsh, tmux

I am creating a few scripts that I'm saving at `$HOME/.local/bin`; path which is added to the `PATH` in `$HOME/.zshrc`. If I execute them through the terminal, all is good. However, when I do `tmux run-shell <script>` it fails.

If I do `echo $SHELL` and `tmux run-shell "echo $SHELL"` both return `/bin/zsh`. If I do `echo $PATH` and `tmux run-shell 'echo $PATH'` things are different; the latter being way shorter than the former.

How can I add paths to the `PATH` so that tmux `run-shell` is able to find them? I read somewhere that it only loads "global environments", but so far I haven't been able to add more to such environment. I tried having `.zshenv`, `.zprofile`, and `zlogin` apart from `.zshrc`.

In case it's worth something, I am running MacOs Ventura, but will be also replicating this setup on Linux.

Any sort of help is very welcome!

Comment: According to the man page of tmux, apparently `run-shell` use `/bin/sh` (and there seems to be no direct/dedicated switch to specify another shell executable/path).

Answer (score 1):

The shell tmux uses inside `run-shell` gets environment variables from the tmux server. Depending on how you started the tmux server and what happened later, the resulting environment may or may not agree with what you see in your interactive Zsh inside tmux or outside of tmux.

The environment of the server is not automatically updated when a client connects. Please see [*How does tmux spawn multiple sessions?*](https://superuser.com/a/1424154/432690) Note tmux creates environment for a child by merging [global environment and session environment](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#GLOBAL_AND_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT). This answer assumes that you want the right `PATH` in the global environment and that you don't set `PATH` in any session environment.

I think if you start a tmux server from within Zsh where `PATH` is what you want, then the tmux server will take this `PATH`; unless e.g. there is `set-environment -g PATH /wrong/path:…` in your `.tmux.conf`.

If you start a tmux server from elsewhere (e.g. from cron or as a service), make sure `PATH` there and then is what you want.

Alternatively use `set-environment -g PATH /right/path:…` in your `.tmux.conf`, so each new tmux server will set the variable on its own, regardless of what it inherits from its parent.

For an already running server you can update `PATH` in the global environment by invoking the following command from a shell that knows the right `PATH`:

```
tmux set-environment -g PATH "$PATH"
```